# Spring Core - Alias and Ids

Tags: spring

I started learning Spring today and came across a strange behavior, so seeking any expert help on the behavior. I defined a bean with an id and verified the bean is available via ApplicationContext and Bean factory. Later created more beans with different IDs but created one alias with the exact same Id of the First Bean (xml snippet below)

```
<!-- Beans -->
<bean id="wolf" class="com.badwolf.spring.SpringWolf">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="wolfy" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="20" />
</bean>

<bean id="sweetWolf" class="com.badwolf.spring.SweetWolf" />

<!-- Aliases -->
<alias name="sweetWolf" alias="wolf" />
```

Now in the implementation class when getting the bean using "wolf" then getting the bean associated with the "Alias". Is this intended behavior of Spring? Do Aliases take precedence over the bean definition (which seems to be the core of Spring)?

What if my project is split into teams and on integration someone has used the same id and alias and all of a sudden a portion of functionality stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are three Spring bean terminology here, name, alias, and id.
Spring bean can have multiple names, aliases, while it can only have one unique id.

Below is reference from [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beanname)

> Every bean has one or more identifiers. These identifiers must be unique within the container that hosts the bean. A bean usually has only one identifier, but if it requires more than one, the extra ones can be considered aliases.

So in your case, bean with id of "wolf" has Spring-generated name ("springwolf"), while bean with id "sweetWolf" has two names, Spring-generated name("sweestWolf") and name alias("wolf") ([spring-bean-names](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/02/spring-bean-names.html)).

Related discussions for alias vs name ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211590/spring-usage-of-alias-vs-names), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220919/spring-bean-alias-usage))

Related discussion for alias vs id ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874505/difference-between-using-bean-id-and-name-in-spring-configuration-file))

Comment: I did understood the concept of name, alias and ID but I could not find a reference in Spring documentation that Spring mandates a "name" of a bean and if a name is not provided then provides a name by itself. Also, I could not find a reference which mentions that Spring uses "name" attribute only to lookup the beans via any factory.